# Calculate exponentially distributed random number

Tags: random-variables, random, exponential-distribution

I have to calc a random timeout value with the following characteristics:

The timeout should be exponentially distributed with the parameter rate.
for example: if the rate is 5 the timeout should occure average 5 times per time unit.

I have now calculated a uniform random-number between 0 and 1. How do I have to calculate the timeout which meets the requirements on the basis of my uniform random number?

Thanky for your help.

Comment: $$X=-\frac{\ln U}5$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the timeout $T \sim \exp(\lambda)$ and let $F_T$ denote its cumulative distribution function. Now let 
$$
F_T^{\leftarrow}(t)= \inf\{x\in R: F_T(x)\geq t\},
$$
be the generalized inverse of $F_T$, also know as the quantile funtion. You can now show that if $U\sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ then
$$
F_T^{\leftarrow}(U) \sim \exp(\lambda).
$$
Using this you can generate samples from a $\exp(\lambda)$ distribution, by sampling from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and sending them through the generalized inverse $F_T^{\leftarrow}$.